# get data from hashmap into highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts, hashmap, angular-chart

Im new to angular and charts, so i choose to work with highcharts, i have this service that return a hashmap i want to put the values into vertical bar i want so replace the static data with the dynamic data from the service using this way:

```
chart = new Chart({
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'errors'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: this.data,
  }]

})
```

and this is my service inside ngOnInit:

```
this.dashboardHttpService.exceptionsByMicroseviceDaily().subscribe(success=> {
this.data=Object(success);
console.log(this.data);
})
```

i got no result, please how vertical bar of high charts work with hashmap

Edit:
this is what `console.log(this.data)` renders:
 {Timeout: 180, ClientHandler: 307, Transport: 199, UnknownHost: 127, Reflections: 140}

ClientHandler:307
Reflections:140
Timeout:180
Transport:199
UnknownHost:127

and this is what i put on my html page:

dashboard.component.html

```html
 <div class="content"> <div [chart]="chart"></div>
```

everything works fine with static data so there's no dependancy or configuration missing or something like that.

Comment: What is the structure of  `Object(success)`? Is it an array? Where in the code do you render your chart? What container is it linked to on your page?

Comment: thank you for replying, plz check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the chart does not work is because your `series` will look like the following when you assigned the dynamic `this.data` to the chart:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: [Timeout: 180, ClientHandler: 307, Transport: 199, UnknownHost: 127, Reflections: 140]
}]
```

This is an incorrect format for `series`. The format should be one of the two below:

**Plot all data points as one**

`series [{ name: 'Population', data:[180, 307, 199, 127, 140] }]`

**Plot all data points as a serie per name**

`series [{ name: 'Timeout', data: [180] }, { name: 'ClientHandler', data: [307] }, { ... }]`

So, you would need to write a loop which divides the response into one of the above formats. Seeing your chart structure, I *think* you are looking for the second approach.

I made a simple `for-loop` which extracts the data from the object for demo purposes:

```
var testdata = {Timeout: 180, ClientHandler: 307, Transport: 199, UnknownHost: 127, Reflections: 140}
var chartdata = []
var i = 0;
Object.keys(testdata).forEach(function(key) {

  chartdata[i++] = {name: key, data: [testdata[key]]};

});
```

After this loop, `chartdata` will be looking like:

`[{ name: 'Timeout', data: [180] }, { name: 'ClientHandler', data: [307] }, { ... }]`

All which is left is change the code from `series` to accept the `chartdata` as the whole series object:

```
series: chartdata
```

The chart will work.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n91qnyLa/) you can find a very simple JSFiddle showing this.

Comment: it's working fine thank you so much, i really appretiate your help